# Javascript to add values, reveal div

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I've modified someone else's Fiddle as a starting point, but here's what I'd like to accomplish:

If the user selects the first option from each drop down, a div that is hidden will appear.  It adds the values that have been assigned to those two options, and then changes the div from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1.  That's it.

Here's the body:

```
<body>

    <select id="selectionA" name="selection" onchange="Place2go(this.value, this.id)">
        <option value="0">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">West</option>
        <option value="9">East</option>
        <option value="18">North</option>
        <option value="27">South</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selectionB" name="selection" onchange="Place2go(this.value, this.id)">
        <option value="0">Select one</option>
        <option value="5">Winter</option>
        <option value="6">Spring</option>
        <option value="7">Summer</option>
        <option value="8">Fall</option>
    </select>

    <p id="output">TEST 123</p>

 </body>
```

Here's the JS:

```
function Place2go(item, where){
    var One = document.getElementById("selectionA").value;
    var Two = document.getElementById("selectionB").value;
    if(One != 0 && Two !=0){
        var Addie = Number(One) + Number(Two);
        switch(Addie){
            case 6:           // IF FIRST SELECTION OF BOTH ARE CHOSEN    1+5
                $("#output")
                    .animate(
                        { opacity: 1 }, 1000
                    );    // EXECUTE YOUR 'GO TO URL' HERE
                break;
            default:
                alert('def');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#output {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px/20px; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ys3GS/55/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rx17afw1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery in jsfiddle, it puts all of the javascript inside of a $(window).load() event. So your function is only defined inside of that event. You can attach the function to the jQuery object and call it that way.

[See my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qxzdn1d/1/). Here's the accompanying code:

HTML:

```
<h2>pick an option</h2>

<select id="selectionA" name="selection" onchange="$(this).Place2go(this.value, this.id)">
    <option value="0">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">West</option>
    <option value="9">East</option>
    <option value="18">North</option>
    <option value="27">South</option>
</select>
<select id="selectionB" name="selection" onchange="$(this).Place2go(this.value, this.id)">
    <option value="0">Select one</option>
    <option value="5">Winter</option>
    <option value="6">Spring</option>
    <option value="7">Summer</option>
    <option value="8">Fall</option>
</select>
<p id="output">TEST 123</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$.fn.Place2go = function (item, where) {
    var One = document.getElementById("selectionA").value;
    var Two = document.getElementById("selectionB").value;
    if (One != 0 && Two != 0) {
        var Addie = Number(One) + Number(Two);
        switch (Addie) {
            case 6:
                // IF FIRST SELECTION OF BOTH ARE CHOSEN    1+5
                $("#output")
                    .animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000); // EXECUTE YOUR 'GO TO URL' HERE
                break;
            default:
                alert('def');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, it was so simple.  Thanks so much!  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only Wrong is in js in final line "});" remove ");" and only let "}" and thats all!

```
function Place2go(item, where) {            
            var One = document.getElementById("selectionA").value;
            var Two = document.getElementById("selectionB").value;
            if(One != 0 && Two !=0){
                var Addie = Number(One) + Number(Two);                         
                switch(Addie){
                    case 6:           // IF FIRST SELECTION OF BOTH ARE CHOSEN    1+5
                        $("#output")
                            .animate(
                                { opacity: 1 }, 1000
                            );    // EXECUTE YOUR 'GO TO URL' HERE
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('def');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I see that I missed that detail in my code too.  Thanks for pointing it out.